# How to extract strings from Hashmap in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an setOnItemClickListener() to my listview. The listview is populated by user data. I have used an Arraylist of Hashmap. My aim is to display the two strings inside the Hashmap as a toast. How do I get both the key and value seperately from the hashmap?

```
liblv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
// I want to extract the key and value strings in the Hashmap
            HashMap<String,String> map  = (HashMap<String, String>) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Comment: Have you heared a bout a tool named **Google**? http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

Does your HashMap only contain one key-value pair? Then the question is why a HashMap is used.

In general when you want to access keys and values of a HashMap you could go through it in a loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
  String key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();
  ...
}
```